# Using a WYSIWYG field in Fieldable Panels Panes

Tags: panels, wysiwyg

I'm using the Fieldable Panels Panes module to allow my users to create pre-styled panels and arrange them on the page using drop and drag.

I've used a Drupal 7 site before where you could include a field that uses the WYSIWYG editor as the widget for that field, so the user can insert a WYSIWYG-authored block of content for the panel.

I can't figure out how to replicate this on my own site. How can I add fields to my Fieldable Panels Panes forms so my users can use the WYSIWYG editor when adding panels? (I have the wysiwyg module with ckeditor library installed.)